# implement sys.exit() in databricks python activity

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm executing python script as databricks python activity in azure datafactory.\

**what I want to do:**

```
import sys

def main():
    flag = True
    if flag:
       sys.exit(0)
    else:
       sys.exit(1)

# If the flag is `True` I want to continue with next python activity,
# otherwise the current activity should fail.
```

So this should continue with next python activity but...

what I'm getting:

[image: SystemExit: 0, To exit use 'exit', 'quit' or Ctrl+D]

Answer (score 0):

This code will always exit(0) because the flag is always True.

The function calls exit(0) and exit(1) are used to reveal the status of the termination of a Python program. The call exit(0) indicates successful execution of a program whereas exit(1) indicates some issue/error occurred while executing a program.

Use `try` and `exception` to catch the exact error message.